# Using jQuery TinySort plugin to sort by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an unordered list with class name .summary_ul with a number of list items of class .summary_ul_li, each of which has a 'val' attribute whose value is a string of letters. I am calling this function from the javascript file:

```
function sort_by_val(){
    var $tosort = $('.summary_ul_li');
    $tosort.tsort({attr:"val"});
}
```

However, $tosort does not sort, and remains in its original order. I am trying to use this plugin:

http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You're only getting the `<ul>` - I think you need to set "$tosort" to `$('.summary_ul .summary_ul_li')`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $('.summary_ul_li') instead of $('.summary_ul'). I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: You might want to add your html to the question.